# Animating View in RelativeLayout from within a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am testing a feature where I would like to animate a view from a ScrollView. I think providing a sample layout would be much easier to understand, so here it goes:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_4"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom_buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame_cart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="130dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_cart"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Summarizing it: main parent is a LinearLayout, containing a header (another LinearLayout), and a ScrollView. In this ScrollView I got a bunch of Views, and over them, there is another View (a FrameLayout containing a Button in this testing case) which I would like to animate  later.

The problem is (or at least what I think of): somehow, the height of the RelativeLayout is computed as wrapped content, and animating that View to the bottom of the screen won't display it, as it goes beyond its parent computed height.

In case it would be relevant, this is the tested animation being fired when I click the button:

```
 AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator animToBottom = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameCart, "translationY", 200);
        animSet.play(animToBottom);
        animSet.setDuration(300);
        animSet.start();
```

Comment: you mean you are trying to animate the direct child of the `ScrollView` which is the relative layout? the relativelayout is taller than the scrollview-(the way it should be) so animating it down is out of screen space, unless it has been scrolled to that position or length, so idk what you really want but before animation starts scroll to that view and animate it to the ScrollView rect.Bottom idk if this is what you want or might work

Comment: I'm trying to animate a FrameLayout (id: frame_cart), that is 2 levels inside the RelativeLayout (which is main container of ScrollView).

Comment: have you got any solution @DoruAdryan